# Xamarin MediaElement: setDataSource failed on URL

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uri, .net-standard, mediaelement

The following works ok:

*using Plugin.[FilePicker;](https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows)*

```
using Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Core;`
...
    private void btnPlaySource_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
        if (fileData == null)
            return; // user canceled file picking
        mediaElement.Source = MediaSource.FromFile(fileData.FilePath);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
```

But these lines throw an exception with a delay of ~7 secs (it's not immediately thrown):

```
    private void btnPlayURL_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        var fileURL = GetGDriveFileURL();
        mediaElement.Source = MediaSource.FromUri(fileURL);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
```

*Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000'*

What could be the reason of the exception? The URL is 100% working, I tested it on a WPF application's MediaElement and it played fine. I also build the application for Android with Android API level 29 SDK.

```
<Grid><xct:MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" Grid.Row="0" AutoPlay="False" ShowsPlaybackControls="True"/>
```

Comment: since the filepicker has been archived by the owner. I suggest  xamarin.essential instead

Comment: Did you come up with a fix for this?  Something very similar seems to be happening to me as well.

Comment: @ashlar64, see my answer below, I switched to Xamarin.Essentials.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the problems were solved using Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker. It allows picking audio from Google Drive if it's connected to the Android device. Although, the problem with URL still remains.

```
//var fileResult = await App.PickAndShow(Xamarin.Essentials.PickOptions.Default);
//if (fileResult == null) return false;
public static async Task<string> PickAndShow(Xamarin.Essentials.PickOptions options)
{
    try {
        Xamarin.Essentials.FileResult result = 
        await Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
        if (result != null) {
            // For certain types of files, like ".mp3" 
            if (result.FileName.EndsWith("mp3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                result.FileName.EndsWith("wav", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // for debug purposes
                bool exists = File.Exists(result.FullPath);
            }
        }
        return result.FullPath;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // The user canceled or something went wrong
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Trying to play a video file from a URL is my problem.  On iOS it works fine but on Android it just crashes.  Hopefully this won't happen in Maui.

Comment: @ashlar64, the core technology for maui is xamarin(.forms) but I hope so this won't.